Нужны свежие туториалы/примеры по inkwell или cranelift
Всех приветствую, столкнулся с проблемой - полным отсутствием рабочих туториалов. Всё что я находил по inkwell (llvm) и cranelift - нерабочий шлак 5-6 летней давности. Каким-то магическим образом получается, что у автора (например) Module - это структура, а у меня - типаж (trait). 
Собственно, поэтому прошу помочь мне найти туториалы, или свежие примеры с использованием одной из вышеупомянутых библиотек.

Лучшее что смог найти - это брать пример с Kaleidoscope Tutorial у inkwell плюс вопросы к ChatGPT.
Кому надо:

Inkwell Kaleidoscope
Моё исполнение (модуль tpl-ir).

